# Strange behavior on stopping php artisan serve

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I change my SQL server from pgsql (localhost) to MySQL (remote host) in the env file

database.php file has this line:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

i run:

```
php artisan serve
```

and I call my page it does not respond and get stuck

After this, I press CTRL+C and close Laravel.

Then I restart the engine PHP artisan serve, and then I get this error:

> Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000 [Sun Sep
>   16 16:05:52 2018] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: Address
>   already in use)

Is there something I am missing.

If I go back to my localhost database of pgsql and don't change the line

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

in my database.php file it works fine. (it should not because I am using a pgsql database)

I also tried using

```
php artisan serve --port 3333
```

but that has given the same behavior.

Comment: make sure other laravel app is not running on 127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear cached data like config, cache, view.

```
php artisan config:clear // cache:clear and view:clear
```

OR

**This can happen when there is already an app running on 127.0.0.1:8000**

You can close that app then it will work. 
OR if you want to run multple apps then use shown below way:

```
php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8888
```

You can try different host ip as well as port no.s

I suggest you should learn how to make a **virtualhost**.
It will let you hit your local project without running this command and you can also make an alias like dev.app.com etc

Comment: restart apache/xampp and try again

Comment: You are changing config.. try to clear config and cache and run server again `config:clear, cache:clear, view:clear` etc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another laravel application is running in this 8000 port. If not, you change the port for this application. like:

```
php artisan serve --port=8080
```

Comment: @NishantSah restart your pc. just for a try.